# How can I do multiple operations in the same initiated line (initiated as a string)

Tags: c#

I have to be able to do multiple operations in an initiated string. The user enters which operation he wants ex. 6+1-8*2/5, but this is variable

```
            'else if (input.Contains("+"))
            {
                string[] splitString = input.Split('+');
                string result = splitString[0].Trim();
                double number1 = double.Parse(result);
                string result2 = splitString[1].Trim();
                double number2 = double.Parse(result2);
                finalResult = number1 + number2;
                Console.Write(Math.Round(finalResult, 2));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(">");
                invoer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (input.Contains("-"))
            {
                string[] splitString = input.Split('-');
                string result = splitString[0].Trim();
                double number1 = double.Parse(result);
                string result2 = splitString[1].Trim();
                double number2 = double.Parse(result2);
                finalResult = number1 - number2;
                Console.Write(Math.Round(finalResult, 2));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(">");
                invoer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (input.Contains("/"))
            {
                string[] splitString = input.Split('/');
                string result = splitString[0].Trim();
                double number1 = double.Parse(result);
                string result2 = splitString[1].Trim();
                double number2 = double.Parse(result2);
                finalResult = number1 / number2;
                Console.Write(Math.Round(finalResult, 2));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(">");
                invoer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (input.Contains("*"))
            {
                string[] splitString = input.Split('*');
                string result = splitString[0].Trim();
                double number1 = double.Parse(result);
                string result2 = splitString[1].Trim();
                double number2 = double.Parse(result2);
                finalResult = number1 * number2;
                Console.Write(Math.Round(finalResult, 2));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(">");
                invoer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            }'
```

The user has to be able to add as many operations as wanted, until he presses Enter

Comment: Yet another ... seems to be calculator day today :D You need to interpret the string. Just looking for an operator won't get you very far. Providing a complete answer to this will surely blast the format of SO, I am afraid.

Comment: you would need to take into account operator order, as * trumps all

Comment: If you split your sample on the `-`, you get "6+1" and "8*2/5", neither of which will correctly parse to a double. You will need to recurse to correctly calculate those parts. Plus you will need to decide what answer you want for "1+2*3": 9 or 7.

Comment: You could "cheat" and use `DataTable` like so: `double result = (double) new DataTable().Compute("6+1-8*2/5", null);`  This returns `3.8`